# How to conditionally include XML in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, debugging

I have some test code in my C# program that I conditionally include/exclude using #if and a debug variable.

There are some settings in a related XML file I would like to also conditionally include/exclude.  Right now I just exclude them with XML comments, but I would like to find a way to conditionally include/exclude them based on the same debug variable I'm using for the C# code.

Comment: using `#if` with the debug macro changes the compiled result, XML files are not compiled.  If you do not care about a particular value, you should have the program parsing the XML ignore certain nodes.

Comment: I understand XML is not compiled.  I just want to be able to exclude some text from the file somehow.  I suppose one route would be to have my C# code simply load a different file for testing, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this within a single file.

Comment: Are you the one providing the XML file?

Comment: Yes.  I just want to modify it temporarily for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

See [web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). They allow the web.config file to be automatically changed for each build configuration (and in VS2012, for each deployment environment).